# Return the item number X in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to provide one piece of content per day storing all items in dynamoDB. I will add new content from time to time but only one piece of content needs to be read per day.

It seems it's not recommended to have incremental Id as primary key on dynamoDB.

Here is what I have at the moment:

content_table

`id, content_title, content_body, content_author, view_count
1b657df9-8582-4990-8250-f00f2194abe9, title_1, body_1, author_1, view_count_1
810162c7-d954-43ff-84bf-c86741d594ee, title_2, body_2, author_2, view_count_2
4fdac916-0644-4237-8124-e3c5fb97b142, title_3, body_3, author_3, view_count_3`

The database will have a low rate of adding new item has I will add new content myself manually.

How can I get the item number XX without querying all the database in nodeJS ?

Should I switch back to a MySQL database ?

Should I use a homemade auto increment even if it's an anti pattern ?

Should I used a time-based uuid, and do a query like, get all ids, sort them, and get the number X in the array ?

Should I use a tool like http://www.stateful.co/ ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the date your hash key, you can then simply get the content from any particular day using [GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html).

```
date, content_title, content_body, content_author, view_count
20180208, title_1, body_1, author_1, view_count_1
20180207, title_2, body_2, author_2, view_count_2
20180206, title_3, body_3, author_3, view_count_3
```

If you think you might have more than one piece of content for any one day in future, you could add a datetime attribute and make this the range key

```
date, datetime, content_title, content_body, content_author, view_count
20180208, 20180208101010, title_1, body_1, author_1, view_count_1
20180208, 20180208111111, title_2, body_2, author_2, view_count_2
20180206, 20180208101010, title_3, body_3, author_3, view_count_3
```

Its then still very fast and simple to execute a [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) to get the content for a particular day.

Note that due to the way DynamoDB distributes throughput, if you choose the second option, you might want to archive old content into another table.